# How do I remove the freewheel side of a flip flop hub?

Tags: hub

[image]I've got one of those flip flop hubs, and I need to remove the freewheel side and either service or replace it as it has started slipping really badly. What tools do I need?
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I think most just come off with some sort of freewheel/cassette removal tool.  About 10 different varieties, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a [freewheel removal tool](http://www.parktool.com/category/freewheel-cassette).

That looks to me like it will take an FR6, but you should measure first if you're planning on buying. Although, this will likely be the only time you ever use it unless you open a bike shop.

Your local bike shop will almost certainly have one of these and be able to whip it off it no time. They might not even charge for such a small job.

Sheldon brown has [instructions](http://sheldonbrown.com/freewheels.html#remove) on the rest the removal. Basically, you just need to put the tool in a vice, place the wheel on it and turn. He recommends using a quick release skewer to secure the tool, but you have solid axles so just be careful.

Comment: its a 16 tooth freewheel. Its pretty standard. Could you link to the kind of tool you mean/

Comment: The tool connects with the two rectangular holes on the outside face of the freewheel. The FR2 is on the first page I linked to.

Comment: I worked in a bike shop, and if someone came in with the wheel off the bike, we would just take it off for free. If the wheel is off and you dont have the nuts on the axle, it takes less than a minute to take that free wheel off. Place the tool in a bench press, insert the wheel, and spin!

Comment: oh, @alex - it is the FR6, you can BARELY see it with the shadow in the picture, but there is a 3rd notch on there (and I am assuming the 4th is hidden by the frame) so my guess is that it is a Dicta, my personal favorite due to its thinner profile!


  [1]: http://bit.ly/10bbtt4 "Dicta Freewheel"

Comment: Oh yeah, I can see it if i tilt my laptop screen. Edited. Cheers.